# php form action failed when I prevented direct access to database.php using .htaccess

Tags: php, html

I edited .htaccess to prevent direct access to database.php file. now this form
action didn't working.

```
<form class="contact" action="database.php" name="contact"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Please post your .htaccess. BTW, there are several better ways for preventing direct access than using .htaccess. Probably, that apache directive is also preventing the form handling.

Comment: I used it to prevent direct access:

<Files database.php>
    Deny from all
</Files>

Comment: @rotvulpix  I used this in .htaccess: 

 <Files database.php>
 Deny from all 
</Files>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to deny from all , and allow your hosting  server IP only access to it,

Here xx.xxx.xx.xx is your server ip,

*.htaccess*

```
 <Files database.php>
     Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from xx.xxx.xx.xx 
 </Files>
```

Comment: I'll try it . If it works I will accept your answer .